# zoom mapView to a certain bounding box on osmdroid

Tags: android, maps, openstreetmap, bounding-box

I want to use the zoomToBoundingBox method to zoom a map to a specific bounding box.
The method does nothing but display the map on zoom level 0.

In the mapView.java source code I found this:

> /**
>            * Zoom the map to enclose the specified bounding box, as closely as possible.
>            * Must be called after display layout is complete, or screen dimensions are not known, and
>            * will always zoom to center of zoom  level 0.
>            * Suggestion: Check getScreenRect(null).getHeight() > 0
>            */

I checked `getScreenRect(null).getHeight() > 0` and it gives me false.

How do you complete display layout programmatically?
What can I do so that the above predicate gives me true?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I addressed it by calling the zoomToBoundingBox() call at the end of the onLayout() method.

I have my own subclass of MapView that I use to insulate me from the map library choice. This class has a clearPoints / addPoint / layoutPoints style of interface. Within the layoutPoints() method I create the itemized overlay lay from the collection of points and create the bounding box that is stored in an instance method of the class.

```
public class MyMapView extends MapView {

// The bounding box around all map points
// Used to determine the correct zoom level to show everything
private int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
private int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
private int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

private BoundingBoxE6 boundingBox;
```

My onLayout() override has:

```
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.osmdroid.views.MapView#onLayout(boolean, int, int, int, int)
 */
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
    super.onLayout(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4);

    // Now that we have laid out the map view,
    // zoom to any bounding box
    if (this.boundingBox != null) {
        this.zoomToBoundingBox(this.boundingBox);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it, but it seems to work for me (except that the zoom appears to be a little too far out, but that's another problem for another time).

Comment: tried this, but cannot create the view with MyMapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

Comment: does that have any impact on the layout.xml file or the way you create the view? if i do : mapView = (MyMapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview); it refuses to perform the cast and crashes...!!!

Comment: I create my map view (actually all of my views) programmatically. I think that there is a way to define "MyMapView" with the right constructors so that the IDE can then create a MyMapView within XML. But that is from hazy "when I first started on Android" reading many years ago.

Comment: @thanasio2 it should work with your xml layout if you use `<my.package.name.MyMapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`.