# Osmdroid maximum zoom level displaying two geo locations

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, osmdroid

I am using **osmdroid** library to render maps. I have two geo points that vary intermittently, and want the org.osmdroid.views.MapView to resize and translate making sure both points are always visible. I can easily re-centre the map on the point mid-way between the two, but how do I set the zoom level to ensure my two points are visible?

UPDATE

```
  //Getting pickup and destination latitude and longitude
                GeoPoint pickupLocation = null;
                if (tripRequest.getPickupLat() != null && tripRequest.getPickupLong() != null) {
                    pickupLocation = new GeoPoint(tripRequest.getPickupLat(), tripRequest.getPickupLong());
                }
                GeoPoint destinationLocation = null;
                if (tripRequest.getDestinationLat() != null && tripRequest.getDestinationLong() != null) {
                    destinationLocation = new GeoPoint(tripRequest.getDestinationLat(), tripRequest.getDestinationLong());
                }

                if (destinationLocation != null && pickupLocation != null) {
                    //Adding destination marker to map
                    Marker destinationLocationMarker = new Marker(map);
                    destinationLocationMarker.setPosition(destinationLocation);
                    destinationLocationMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
                    destinationLocationMarker.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.pin_green_small));
                    map.getOverlays().add(destinationLocationMarker);
                    //Adding pickup marker to map
                    Marker pickupLocationMarker = new Marker(map);
                    pickupLocationMarker.setPosition(pickupLocation);
                    pickupLocationMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_BOTTOM);
                    pickupLocationMarker.setIcon(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.pin_red_small));
                    map.getOverlays().add(pickupLocationMarker);


                    BoundingBox boundingBox = BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints(Arrays.asList(destinationLocation, pickupLocation));
                    mapController = map.getController();

                    mapController.setCenter(boundingBox.getCenter());

                    mapController.setZoom(10);// I need to set this zoom properly
                    touchListener = new TouchListener();
                    map.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use zoomToBoundingBox. It should work and if it doesn't problem will be elsewhere.

Try:

```
map.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, false);
map.invalidate();
```

It this still don't work, check this response: 
[zoom mapView to a certain bounding box on osmdroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658277/zoom-mapview-to-a-certain-bounding-box-on-osmdroid#15723565)

If you really want to calculate zoom yourself you can always find an inspiration in [source code of zoomToBoundingBox method](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/39f7d85fc2cc4193c3021e52a9816170a9fa653c/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.java#L435) and modify the calculation to fit your needs.

Comment: I commented to Spy's response that I already tried: map.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, false); and it doesn't work. I don't believe there is a problem elsewhere; since the map works fine with static zoom levels.

Comment: @MarianneAbdelmalek  That is strange. I'm quit sure I used this method recently and it has been working. Maybe try to reproduce the functionality from [source](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/39f7d85fc2cc4193c3021e52a9816170a9fa653c/osmdroid-android/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/views/MapView.java#L435) in your code and step through it using debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your are looking for zoom to bounds which is in mapview or map controller. Use the max/min lat lon from your points.  You'll want to test at the date line and equator

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated to add my code. I can center to a bounding box, but don't seem to be able to use that bounding box in zoom.

Comment: I also tried map.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, false); But it doesn't work.